# PHP fputcsv showing scientific notation instead of long intergers

Tags: php, csv, fputcsv

When creating file in csv using fputcsv then long integers show in scientific notation.

Example  -
0133211000000140 is showing 1.33211E+14

```
    fputcsv($file, array('Id','DESTINATION_ACCOUNT','SOURCE_ACCOUNT'));
     if(!empty($data)){
        foreach($data as $key => $row){
            fputcsv($file,[$row['ID']
                               $row['DESTINATION_ACCOUNT'],  -- scientific notation instead of long integer
                               $row['SOURCE_ACCOUNT'] -- scientific notation instead of long integer
                        ]
                    );
        }
     }
```

Comment: Have you looked at the actual CSV file contents (not in a spreadsheet app)?

Comment: No, I haven't looked from CSV file contents. I am checking from spreadsheet app. Is it possible to show long integer accurate  in CSV when it showing spreadsheet app?

Comment: The CSV content is probably still a number. Spreadsheet software would sometimes reformat numbers in scientific notation. Open the CSV with a text editor and see the raw data for yourself.

Comment: The CSV content is in number format. But when we check from spreadsheet it reform in scientific notation. How could we get actual long integer when check from spreadsheet?

Comment: You can try to convert your integers into strings before you write the data into CSV. Another option - you can change the cell format for your column in your spreadsheet app.

Comment: @Md.AbdulHannan Are you using PHPExcel library or willing to use?

Comment: @user1597430 - Conversion  not working when save data into csv. How can change the cell format in csv when save data use fputcsv?

Comment: @nice_dev - No, currently i am using fputcsv to save data in csv. If there is no solution then need to change csv to excel format.

Comment: @Md.AbdulHannan Ok but with the help of PHPExcel library you can set the cell format to text to make it work.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

That happens with floating points that have lots of digits:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php

> If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the int type, it will
> be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in
> a number beyond the bounds of the int type will return a float
> instead.
> (...)
>
> ```php
> $large_number = 9223372036854775808;
> var_dump($large_number);                     // float(9.2233720368548E+18)
> ```

`echo gettype(1.33211E+14);` outputs: `double`.

If you do `printf('%d', '1.33211E+14');`, or `printf('%.0f', '1.33211E+14');`, or `echo (int)1.33211E+14;`, you'll get a decimal representation. That representation might be wrong.

```php
<?php
printf('%.0f', 66666666666666666);
```

outputted:

```
66666666666666664
```

If you're handling numbers larger than `PHP_MAX_INT`, it may be better to have them represented as strings and use [GMP](https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.gmp.php) for the operations.